# If a cell contains a certain character replace the whole cell in r

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have several cells in a dataframe contain a number followed by an asterisk. I would like to replace the data in the cells with the * with NA. Here's sample data

```
a<-c(1.23,"4.2*", 5,6,"8*")
b<-c(0.01,0.5,"3.687*",9,10)
c<-data.frame(a,b)
c
```

I tried c[c=="*"]<-NA but that only replaces cells that only contain the *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also use

```
c[] <- lapply(c, function(x) replace(x, grep("[*]", x), NA))
c
#    a    b
#1 1.23 0.01
#2 <NA>  0.5
#3    5 <NA>
#4    6    9
#5 <NA>   10
```

Comment: Or maybe something like `lapply(c, function(x) type.convert(replace(as.character(x), grep("[*]", x), NA)))` to get numbers where numbers (probably) should be. In magrittrish: `lapply(c, . %>% as.character %>% replace(grep("[*]", .), NA) %>% type.convert)`

Answer (score 6):

Try coercing to numeric:

```
data.frame( a = as.numeric(a), b = as.numeric(b) )

     a     b
1 1.23  0.01
2   NA  0.50
3 5.00    NA
4 6.00  9.00
5   NA 10.00
```

Any invalid numbers will become NA. The downside to the OP's preferred approach is that you end up with a data.frame full of factors or characters, when it seems likely that you should use numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the insight however, my data.frame is much larger and has some columns that contain characters (I realize I did not make this clear in my post). When the column contains characters I want the function to do the same, replace any characters that contain a * with NA. Another person posted a response that would have solved this below but see now it has been deleted. Could this please be restored or provide an alternative?

Comment: That was an important piece to leave out.

Comment: try `is.na(c) <- sapply(c, grepl, pattern="\\*")`

Comment: Thanks Frank. Also note that c represents an illustrative data frame. If you were just going to perform your solution to c, without having a and b as separate vectors the function would not work.  Here is what I tried data.frame(as.numeric(c$a),as.numeric(c$b)). The numbers in the columns do not match the original numbers of a and b.

Comment: @Danny That's because you're playing with fire here. When you use `data.frame` on character vectors -- which is what `a` and `b` are in the example -- they are converted into factors. Factors encode strings with integers under the hood. These underlying integers are what you see if you try `as.numeric` or `as.integer` on it at this point. You can use `as.numeric(as.character(c$a))` to get around the dilemma, but really it's best to avoid the issue if you can.

Comment: @Danny Not sure you noticed, but the other answer is back.

Answer (score 1):

```
c[apply(c, 1:2, function(i) grepl('\\*', i))] <- NA
c
#     a    b
#1 1.23 0.01
#2 <NA>  0.5
#3    5 <NA>
#4    6    9
#5 <NA>   10
```

Comment: Why should one use `c[apply(c, 1:2, ...` when simply `2` would work? Like `c[apply(c, 2, ...`